# Detect stylus eraser button on WPF

Tags: wpf, touch, stylus-pen

Is there any way to detect that the stylus eraser button is pressed on a WPF element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer seems to be to detect if the pen is Inverted.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ms607230(VS.110).aspx

(tested on Lenovo x61 tablet)

In MainWindow.Xaml

```
<TextBlock Name="textBox"
        Text="Hello World!" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
        StylusDown="TextBlock_StylusDown_1"/>
```

In MainWindow.Xaml.cs

```
 private void TextBlock_StylusDown_1(object sender, StylusDownEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Inverted)
            textBox.Text = "I've been erased";
        else
            textBox.Text = "Normal stylus";
    }
```

Comment: I wrote the same code but the e.Inverted always come as false. Do you think that it is a hardware issue? I'm using a Samsung XE700T1A.

Comment: More likely driver than hardware, but it is a possibilty.